# Implementing a C++ convert on invoke function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I would like to implement a specialized invoke with extra conversion on the arguments using C++11/14. Basically, the idea is:

```cpp
struct Foo {
  private:
    void* ptr;
  public:
    void* get();
};


template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto convert_invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  // not sure how to do here with C++11/14
}

// caller side
int simple(float* f1, size_t N) {
  // doing something interesting
}

// ideally I would like to call the following:
Foo foo;
size_t n = 10;

convert_invoke(simple, foo, n); // internally calls simple((float*)foo.get(), n);
```

The idea here is when the argument is of type `Foo`, I will do some specialized processing like getting the `void*` pointer and cast it to the corresponding argument type defined in `simple`. How can I implement this in `convert_invoke`?

Comment: How does `foo` know what type of data to return?

Comment: Foo's pointer is `void*` type, and the type to cast is defined in simple by users. In this case, it's `float*`.

Comment: But how does `Foo::get` know to return float data instead of double or int data?

Comment: `simple` is defined by user. We can do things like `function_traits` to extract the type of argument.

Comment: Forwarding a value unless it's `Foo`, otherwise forwarding the result of `get()` is not that difficult. Just basic specialization. The problem though is determining the pointer to convert to, at the same time. This whole thing smells C-ish. C++ is meant to be type-safe. That means none of the `void *` games. I would focus on spending some effort into making everything type-safe and getting rid of `void *`, as the first order of business.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: *"The problem though is determining the pointer to convert to"* Class with conversion operator to any pointer can do the job.

Comment: A solution to this will need up very use case specific to the point where you might as well call a function and do the conversions explicitly. For example, how does `convert_invoke` know to pass in a member of foo to the callable instead of foo itself?

Comment: I suspect you are headed down the ill-fated path known as "[XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)". When you start from a structure containing a `void *`, you're probably starting from a flawed position. Rather than forging ahead, you probably should backtrack a bit. Not definitely, but probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like:

```
// Wrapper to allow conversion to expected pointer.
struct FooWrapper
{
    void* p;

    // Allow conversion to any pointer type
    template <typename T>  
    operator T* () { return (T*) p; }
};

// Identity function by default
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) convert(T&& t) // C++14
// auto convert(T&& t) -> decltype(std::forward<T>(t)) // C++11
{ return std::forward<T>(t); }

// special case for Foo, probably need other overloads for Foo&& and cv versions
auto convert(Foo& foo) { return FooWrapper{foo.get()}; }

// Your function
template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto convert_invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return f(convert(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bea1a59b863bfc3)